# shapeless calling value on lazy make a StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

While learning shapeless via this useful [guide](https://github.com/davegurnell/shapeless-guide)

I was trying to merge what I have learned from [this](https://github.com/davegurnell/shapeless-guide/blob/develop/src/pages/generic/lazy.md) in [this exercice](https://github.com/davegurnell/shapeless-guide/blob/develop/src/pages/generic/exercises.md.disabled)

The result is this code :

```
import shapeless._
object GenericV3 {


trait CsvEncoder[A] {
    def width: Int
    def encode(value: A): List[String]
  }

  def createEncoder[A](cols: Int)(func: A => List[String]): CsvEncoder[A] =
    new CsvEncoder[A] {
      val width = cols
      def encode(value: A): List[String] =
        func(value)
    }

  implicit val stringEncoder: CsvEncoder[String] =
    createEncoder(1)(str => List(str))

  implicit val intEncoder: CsvEncoder[Int] =
    createEncoder(1)(num => List(num.toString))

  implicit val booleanEncoder: CsvEncoder[Boolean] =
    createEncoder(1)(bool => List(if(bool) "cone" else "glass"))

  implicit val doubleEncoder: CsvEncoder[Double] =
    createEncoder(1)(d => List(d.toString))

  import shapeless.{HList, HNil, ::}

  implicit val hnilEncoder: CsvEncoder[HNil] =
    createEncoder(0)(hnil => Nil)

  implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](
                                            implicit
                                            hEncoder: Lazy[CsvEncoder[H]],
                                            tEncoder: CsvEncoder[T]
                                          ): CsvEncoder[H :: T] =
    createEncoder(hEncoder.value.width + tEncoder.width) {
      case h :: t =>
        hEncoder.value.encode(h) ++ tEncoder.encode(t)
    }


  import shapeless.{Coproduct, CNil, :+:, Inl, Inr}

  implicit val cnilEncoder: CsvEncoder[CNil] =
    createEncoder(0) { cnil =>
      throw new Exception("The impossible has happened!")
    }

  implicit def coproductEncoder[H, T <: Coproduct](
                                                    implicit
                                                    hEncoder: Lazy[CsvEncoder[H]],
                                                    tEncoder: CsvEncoder[T]
                                                  ): CsvEncoder[H :+: T] =
    createEncoder(hEncoder.value.width + tEncoder.width) {
      case Inl(h) => hEncoder.value.encode(h) ++ List.fill(tEncoder.width)("")
      case Inr(t) => List.fill(hEncoder.value.width)("") ++ tEncoder.encode(t)
    }


  import shapeless.Generic

  implicit def genericEncoder[A, R](
                                     implicit
                                     gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
                                     lEncoder: Lazy[CsvEncoder[R]]
                                   ): CsvEncoder[A] =
    createEncoder(lEncoder.value.width) { value =>
      lEncoder.value.encode(gen.to(value))
    }


  def writeCsv[A](values: List[A])(implicit encoder: CsvEncoder[A]): String =
    values.map(encoder.encode).map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
}
```

when calling `GenericV3.writeCsv` with a sealed case class that has a case containing the sealed case class itself.

the example from the guide :

```
sealed trait Tree[A]
    final case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
    final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
```

I got a StackOverflowError at runtime. 
Exemple

```
GenericV3.writeCsv[Tree[String]](List(Branch(Leaf("toto"),Leaf("titi"))))
```

The error is produced because I call `hEncoder.value.width` before matching Inl and Inr.

I tried to read how it's done in other libs.
And I have seen [this](https://github.com/melrief/pureconfig/blob/06ec5ab3201b359d757cd8138ae64459bc210559/src/main/scala/pureconfig/ConfigConvert.scala#L146) which looks the same.

So I think I missed something.

ps : I would like to thank to the author of this [guide](https://github.com/davegurnell/shapeless-guide) it's very helpful

Comment: Basically, you've given an answer to your own question - we can't use width-aligned encoding for binary trees or other recursive structures due to their possibly infinite size. Library you've listed uses tree-like HOCON encoding similar to JSON, not width-aligned table format.